# tabBarController didSelect does not get called

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a problem with

`tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`

delegate firing. The problem lies when I try to use self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex and change a tab programmatically. Once I use selectedIndex and go back to a previous tab and click on the tabBarItem the delegate does not fire anymore. Delegate only fires if I do not use selectedIndex but once i use it the didSelect delegate never fires again even if I tap on the tabBar item. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: so it would look something like VC0 clicks to VC1(VC0 delegate fires) and VC1 uses selectedindex 0 goes back to VC0 but when i click on anything in VC0 the delegate is not fired

Comment: Solved- The problem was that I had self.tabBarController.delegate = self in the other VC which made them the delegate after using selectedIndex. What I ended up doing was only make one VC the delegate and that solved the problem of programmatically changing tabBarViews.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call delegate programmatically like below
For eg.  I need to select SettingsTab which is at 4th index, i can achieve using this code.  Here didSelect is also called programmatically

```
if let tabbarC = self.tabBarController{
        tabbarC.selectedIndex = 4
        let setting = tabbarC.viewControllers![4]
        self.tabBarController(tabbarC, didSelect: setting)

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried out this code and it works really well to start the delegate again. I think the problem was that I had self.tabBarController.delegate = self in the other VC which made them the delegate after using selectedIndex. What i did was only make one VC the delegate and that solved the problem of programmatically changing tabBarViews.

Answer (score 1):

Tabbar delegate is called only in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically.

Comment: thank you for your response, how would you go about changing tabBars without using selectedIndex programmatically?

Comment: You can change tabbar programmatically - tabBar Controller.selectedIndex = index

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who had the issue with `UITabBarController` delegate with [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero). the problem is with Hero transition `delegate` and solution is to put your tabBarController in a `ViewController` as a container. Then setup Hero on the container and problem solves.

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [...]
let container = UIViewController()
container.addChild(tabBarController)
container.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
tabBarController.didMove(toParent: container)
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.view.frame.width, height: container.view.frame.height)
container.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
container.hero.isEnabled = true
container.modalAnimationType = .slide(direction: .left)
rootViewController.present(container, animated: true, completion: nil)
```