# DidSelect TabBar Item Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a UITabBarController with two View Controllers Embedded into it. I implemented the did select tab bar method where when the user selects a tab, it passes a value into that controller. However when the tabBarController loads for the first time, the did select method is not called even though I have

```
self.selectedIndex = 0
```

Which selects the first index. Basically I am just trying to automatically select the first tab Bar Item when the view loads, and have it call the didSelectTabBarItem method

```
  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is similar to this one.
[tabBarController didSelect does not get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227742/tabbarcontroller-didselect-does-not-get-called)

```
optional func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                     didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

In iOS v3.0 and later, the tab bar controller calls this method regardless of whether the selected view controller changed. In addition, it is called only in response to user taps in the tab bar and is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add this:

```
    self.delegate = self
```

Answer (score -1):

> Copy this in your code

```
class HomeTabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    var isIpad = false
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    var index = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self


        APPDELEGATE.tabBar = self 

    }

}

extension HomeTabBarVC : UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        print("the last selected index is : \(selectedIndex)")
        APPDELEGATE.tabBarLastSelectedIndex = selectedIndex 
        print("the current selected index is : \(String(describing: tabBar.items?.index(of: item)))")
        APPDELEGATE.tabBarCurrentSelectedIndex = tabBar.items?.index(of: item) ?? 0
        }

   }
```

In appdelegate declare this variable,

```
 var tabBar : UITabBarController?
```